# Generate WSDL and Copy in Maven Projects

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I can generate WSDL directly from service GUI as picture below.

[image: Without Maven Project]

But In the Maven project I don't see such "Generate and Copy WSDL...". My question is How to enable it in Maven Project ?

[image]

Is there anything that I am missing. I am also attaching my pom.xml.

Thank you.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.avalant</groupId>
    <artifactId>OTPMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>OTPMaven</name>
    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <showDeprecation>false</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have not got answer to this question. I have found temporary solution.

I am using command line. JDK's wsgen command to generate required output.

```
@echo off
set WSGEN="C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\wsgen.exe"
set J1="C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\lib\tools.jar"
set J2="C:\Java\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\modules\webservices-osgi.jar"
set J3="C:\Java\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\modules\endorsed\webservices-api-osgi.jar"
set J4="C:\Java\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\modules\jaxb-osgi.jar"
set J5="C:\Java\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\modules\endorsed\jaxb-api-osgi.jar"
set J6="C:\Java\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\modules\javax.ejb.jar"
set J7="D:\NetBeansProjects\OTP\target\OTP-1.0\WEB-INF\lib\commons-lang3-3.1.jar"
set J8="D:\NetBeansProjects\OTP\target\OTP-1.0\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.8.jar"
set OUTPUT_DIR="D:\NetBeansProjects\OTP"
@echo on
%WSGEN% -classpath %J1%;%OUTPUT_DIR%\target\classes;%J2%;%J3%;%J4%;%J5%;%J6%;%J7%;%J8%; -d %OUTPUT_DIR%\jax-ws -Xendorsed -keep -wsdl -r %OUTPUT_DIR%\jax-ws -s %OUTPUT_DIR%\jax-ws -verbose com.avalant.ws.GenerateOTPWS
```